# echo session data in ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, session

I am using the following ajax code to login a user by passing the form data entered to my validate_login.php page:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function() {
$(document).on('click', '#submit', function() {
var myusername = $("#myusername").val();
var mypassword = $("#mypassword").val();
if (myusername == null || myusername == "" || mypassword == null || mypassword == "") {
if (myusername == null || myusername == "") { document.forms["form"]["myusername"].style.border = "2px solid #963634";}
if (mypassword == null || mypassword == "") { document.forms["form"]["mypassword"].style.border = "2px solid #963634";}
$( ".home_column" ).effect( "shake" ); 
} else {
// Returns successful data submission message when the entered information is stored in database.
$.post("include/validate_login.php", {
username1: myusername,
password1: mypassword
}, function(data) {
if(data == 'login_wrong') {
$(".home_column").flip({
    direction:'lr',
        color: 'rgba(138, 138, 138, 0.2)', 
            content:'<h21>Incorrect Login Details</h21>'
})  
setTimeout(
  function() 
  {
   $(".home_column").revertFlip()
  }, 2500);  }else{
  if(data == 'login_success') {
  $(".home_column").flip({
    direction:'lr',
        color: 'rgba(138, 138, 138, 0.2)', 
            content:'<h21>Hello <? echo $_SESSION['username']; ?></h21><br/><br/><h21>Login In...</h21>'
})  
setTimeout(
  function() 
  {
   window.location = 'dashboard.php'; 
  }, 2500);

  } }
$('#form')[0].reset(); // To reset form fields
});
}
});
});

</script>
```

I want to point your attention to this part of my code:

```
if(data == 'login_success') {
      $(".home_column").flip({
        direction:'lr',
            color: 'rgba(138, 138, 138, 0.2)', 
                content:'<h21>Hello <? echo $_SESSION['username']; ?></h21><br/><br/><h21>Login In...</h21>'
    })
```

what I'm doing is passing the form data to my php page validate_login.php, this runs a MySQL query to check if the username and password match. If they do then login_success is echoed and this value is passed back to my ajax script as data. This all works fine, the user is logged in and it should echo the users first name to say 'Hello Mark Login In...'

I am trying to do this using a session which is the users first name, and i define this in my validate_login.php page here:

```
session_start();  

$query = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE user_name = '$username' UNION
SELECT * FROM $tbl_name2 where user_name = '$username'"; 
$result = mysql_query($query) or die( mysql_error() );
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

$hashed_pass = crypt($password, $Blowfish_Pre . $row['salt'] . $Blowfish_End);

if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {   // Check Username Exists

if($hashed_pass === $row['user_password_hash']) {   // Check Password is valid
$_SESSION['id']=$row['user_id'];       //Start User Session
$_SESSION['user']=$username;
$_SESSION['username']=$row['user_first_name'];
$_SESSION['username2']=$row['user_last_name'];
$_SESSION['allowance']=$row['allowance'];
$_SESSION['privelleges']=$row['privelleges'];
$sql2 = mysql_query("UPDATE $tbl_name2 SET user_failed_logins = '0', user_status = 'online' WHERE user_name = '".$username."'");
$result2=mysql_query($sql2); 
$sql3 = mysql_query("UPDATE $tbl_name SET user_failed_logins = '0', user_status = 'online' WHERE user_name = '".$username."'");
$result3=mysql_query($sql2); //Start User Session

echo "login_success";
```

for some reason, the name will only sometimes be displayed and then other times it won't. I would say it's 50/50.

Is there a reason for this? Please can someone show me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks,

Comment: the PHP code is executed on the server. So, if $_SESSIOn is empty, it is still so after your ajax call (because it was sent to the client before the call, when the original page was transmitted).

Comment: One more hint, although off topic: mysql_* functions are deprecated. It is strongly recommended not to use them.

Comment: @Burki thank you for your comments, is there a way around this then?

Comment: Yes there is: Print the required information (in your case the user's name), and read the printed value via your ajax request.

Answer (score 0):

you page is already in the client's browser by the time you call ajax to login the user. change your $.post function callback to return user data from server and use jQuery to change your home_column content.